# Is there a Azure replica server for Azure vms?

Tags: hyper-v, azure

We are currently using a Virtual machine in azure and are currently looking at our recovery side of the Azure solution.

In our on site recovery we use Hyper-V Replication mode Replica to a Hyper-V replica server.

The above hyper-v option it obviously creates a seamlessly makes a copy of the server from the primary to the replica server and allows for us to trigger a failover to the replica server.

I have looked around the solution and the closet I can get is azure site recovery but it doesn't talk about azure to azure vms.

With the above Hyper-V model in mind is this something that Azure can do? If so can someone point me in the direction of a tech article?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks for the link but it doesn't explain how vms within a availability set are kept in data sync like hyper v replication, would you know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no service that creates a running replica of a VM in Azure.  Someone mentioned Availability Sets in a comment under your question. Availability Sets have nothing to do with repliction; they are specifically designed to separate your VMs into different fault domains (e.g. physical racks) and update domains (e.g. when the host OS is update).

You would need to maintain an additional VM on your own and fail over to it when needed (which could be a cold-standby waiting to be started, or a warm standby which is running, and where you direct traffic to it).

Note that VMs in Azure support custom probes for custom health check endpoints, so you could easily direct traffic to an alternate VM, should something go wrong with a primary VM.

Also, Azure VM vhd's are stored in Azure Storage (blobs). You can take a snapshot of a blob (near-instant operation), and then re-inflate the snapshot by copying it to its own page blob and mounting that as a vhd (as a quick way of replicating  a VM). A blob-to-blob or snapshot-to-blob copy may take place within the same storage account or different storage accounts, making it possible to send a VM copy to an alternate region, for DR purposes.

Comment: thanks mate, i wondered if this was the case but thought id ask incase i was missing the point.

do you have any instructions etc on the snapshot option?

Comment: for people looking. I am leaving this and looking at software like cloudxplorer to fill my need.